# Synchronize Changes To A Textfield

Tags: actionscript-3, design-patterns, networking, communication

I'm experimenting with P2P on Flash, and I've come across a little hurdle that I'd like to clarify before moving forward. The technology itself (Flash) doesn't matter for this problem, as I think this problem occurs in other languages.

I'm trying to create a document that can be edited "live" by multiple people. Just like Google Docs pretty much. But I'm wondering, how would you suggest synchronizing everyone's text? I mean, should I message everyone with all the text in the text field every time someone makes a change? That seems very inefficient.

I'm thinking there has to be a design pattern that I can learn and implement, but I'm not sure where to start.

Optimally, the application should send the connected clients only the changes that have occurred to the document, and have some sort of buffer or error correction that can be used for retrieving earlier changes that may have been missed. Is there any established design pattern that deals with this type of issue?

Thanks,
Sandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your "Optimally" solution is actually the one you should go for.

each textfield has a model, the model has a history (a FILO storing last, let's say, 10 values).
every time you edit that textfield you push the whole text into the model and send the delta to other connected clients.
as other clients receive the data they just pick the last value from the model and merge it to the received data.

you can refine the mechanism by putting an idle timer in the middle: as a user types something in the textfield you flag that model as "toBeSentThroughTheNet" and you start a timer. as the timer "ticks" (TimerEvent.TIMER) you stop it, collect the flagged data and send it to other clients. just remember to reset the timer everytime the user is actually typing (a semplification coul be keydown = reset, keyup = start).

one more optimization could be send the data packed in a compressed bytearray, but this requires you write your own protocol and may be not so an easy and quick path :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can understand what you mean by tracking the changes and sending only that through. I'm not sure how to tell "what" has changed though. I think that's more so what I'm stuck on. I supposed for my document, I could use some sort of DOM and perhaps only send an identifier and the updated data?

Comment: yes, that could be a good idea. you'd shrink the bandwidth usage if you send commands telling "hey there's a new object" or "hey the object id=15 changed to 'ciao'".

Comment: actually...a "whole" DOM may be an overkill, in order to do that you could just map each managed object with an id into a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is that everyone can edit the document at the same time and the changes should be propagated to everyone and no changes should be lost, then it is a non-trivial problem. There are few different approaches out there, but one that is quite robust is [Operational Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation). This is the same algorithm that Google Docs uses for collaborative editing.

[Understanding and Applying Operational Transformation](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/understanding-and-applying-operational-transformation) and the attendant [hacker news](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1919803) discussion are probably other good places to start.

The [Wave Protocol](https://sites.google.com/a/waveprotocol.org/wave-protocol/code/installation) was released as open source so you can take a look on how it is implemented.

You could of course forgo the tricky synchronization and just allow people to take turns and only one person can edit the document at a time and this person just pushes the changes to the remainder of the group.